# Show DataStore protobuf settings in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, state, android-jetpack-compose, datastore

I'm having an issue trying to display the data saved in my DataStore on startup in Jetpack Compose.

I have a data store set using protocol buffers to serialize the data. I create the datastore

```
val Context.networkSettingsDataStore: DataStore<NetworkSettings> by dataStore(
     fileName = "network_settings.pb",
     serializer = NetworkSettingsSerializer
)
```

and turn it into a livedata object in the view model

```
val networkSettingsLive = dataStore.data.catch { e ->
    if (e is IOException) { // 2
        emit(NetworkSettings.getDefaultInstance())
    } else {
        throw e
    }
}.asLiveData()
```

Then in my @Composable I try observing this data asState

```
@Composable
fun mycomposable(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    val networkSettings by viewModel.networkSettingsLive.observeAsState(initial = NetworkSettings.getDefaultInstance())
    val address by remember { mutableStateOf(networkSettings.address) }
    Text(text = address)
}
```

I've confirmed that the data *is* in the datastore, and saving properly. I've put some print  statements in the composible and the data from the datastore makes it, eventually, but never actually displays in my view. I want to say I'm not properly setting my data as Stateful the right way, but I think it could also be not reading from the data store the right way.
Is there a display the data from the datastore in the composable, while displaying the initial data on start up as well as live changes?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.
What I had to do is define the state variables in the composable, and later set them via a state controlled variable in the view model, then set that variable with what's in the dataStore sometime after initilization.

```
class MyActivity(): Activity {
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        MainScope.launch {
            val networkSettings = viewModel.networkSettingsFlow.firstOrNull()
            if (networkSettings != null) {
                viewModel.mutableNetworkSettings.value = networkSettings
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModel(): ViewModel {
    val networkSettingsFlow = dataStore.data
    val mutableNetworkSettings = mutableStateOf(NetworkSettings.getInstance()
}

@Composable
fun NetworkSettings(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
     val networkSettings by viewModel.mutableNetworkSettings
     var address by remember { mutableStateOf(networkSettings.address) }
     address = networkSettings.address  
     Text(text = address)
}
```